# Adjust custom view's reported size to include drawn graphics

Tags: android, canvas, view, measure

I have a custom view class (call it `FooView`) that I use as the root element of an xml layout.  `FooView`, in its `onDraw()`, uses `canvas` to draw a shape at the bottom edge of `FooView`.

I think that in order for `FooView` to not cut off the shape, I need to override its `onMeasure` and do something that modifies `FooView`'s reported height so that it now includes that of the the drawn shape.

Is that correct?  And if so, what do I need to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you're creating a custom View, you'll need to override `onMeasure()` and provide the size that you need it to be.

So, in the method signature for `onMeasure`, you'll get two parameters:

- widthMeasureSpec
- heightMeasureSpec

You should use the `MeasureSpec` class to get the restrictions you should respect when sizing the View.

```
/*
 * This will be one of MeasureSpec.EXACTLY, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST, 
 * or MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED
 */
int mode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);

//This will be a dimension in pixels
int pixelSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);
```

If you get `MeasureSpec.EXACTLY`, then you should use the `pixelSize` value for your measured width, no matter what.

If you get `MeasureSpec.AT_MOST`, you should just make sure that you set the measured width no greater than `pixelSize`.

If you get `MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED`, you can take as much room as you need. I usually just interpret this as `WRAP_CONTENT`.

So your `onMeasure()` method may look something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure (int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
    int wMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthSpec);
    int hMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightSpec);
    int wSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthSpec);
    int hSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightSpec);

    int measuredWidth = 0;
    int measuredHeight = 0;

    if (wMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
        measuredWidth = wSize;
    } else {
        //Calculate how many pixels width you need to draw your View properly
        measuredWidth = calculateDesiredWidth();

        if (wMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
            measuredWidth = Math.min(measuredWidth, wSize);
        }
    }

    if (hMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
        measuredHeight = hSize;
    } else {
        //Calculate how many pixels height you need to draw your View properly
        measuredHeight = calculateDesiredHeight();

        if (hMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
            measuredHeight = Math.min(measuredHeight, hSize);
        }
    }

    setMeasuredDimension(measuredWidth, measuredHeight);
}
```

Comment: Great response!  Thanks.  Just want to add that if the container view has child views __in addition__ to the custom graphics (e.g. if the container is a subclass of `LinearLayout`), calling `getMeasuredHeight()` or `getMeasuredWidth()` in `measure()` (after a call to `super.onMeasure(widthSpec, heightSpec)`) will give you the container's desired dimensions with just the child views contributing (not the custom drawing).  Updating the container's desired dimensions to include the custom drawing then just entails adding to these dimensions and calling `setMeasuredDimension()` with the result.

Comment: You're welcome. :) That's true if it's a subclass of `ViewGroup` that already handles measurement (e.g. `LinearLayout` as you said), but if you just subclassed `ViewGroup` you'd have to implement the measurement and layout for any children you add. There's also a bunch of helper methods on `ViewGroup` like `measureChild()`, `measureChildren()`, `measureChildrenWithMargins()` and stuff like that to make measuring all the child views based on their `LayoutParams` easier.